# attempting to write a generalized function containing modify_if

Tags: r, arrays, function, purrr

I'm writing a microsimulation of a population.  Each organism can be at any one of four stages, and at each of these stages there is a chance of them dying.  I would like to write a generalised function, or perhaps use an apply statement that evaluates each element of a vector, pulls out the stage level (1-4) and then calculates if that particular individual dies, and thus goes to status 0.  Here is my mwe.

```
library(tidyverse)
p1 <- 0.50
p2 <- 0.45
p3 <- 0.65
p4 <- 0.55

## create initial population
status <- as.numeric(sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE))
status
## check each stage and modify accordingly if that individual dies
status %<>% modify_if(~ .x == 4, ~rbinom(1, 1, p4) * 4)
status
status %<>% modify_if(~ .x == 3, ~rbinom(1, 1, p3) * 3)
status
status %<>% modify_if(~ .x == 2, ~rbinom(1, 1, p2) * 2)
status
status %<>% modify_if(~ .x == 1, ~rbinom(1, 1, p1) * 1)
status
```

Now this works if perform the calculation on each stage separately, but trying to produce a generalized function version, as such, fails. The other part that is difficult is to get the function to evaluate each element of the array independently.  By way of example I don't want all values of 4 converted to 0, only a selection of them, i.e. want the rbinom evaluation performed on each instance of 4 in the array.

```
died <- function (vec, day) {
    vec %<>% modify_if(~ .x == day, ~rbinom(1, 1, paste("p", day, sep = "")) * day)
    vec
    }

newvec <- died(vec = status, day = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste("p", day, sep = "")` is just a string and R does not know how to evaluate it in the function `died`. There are ways in which you can evaluate a string object but it makes code ugly in this case. You can instead create a vector and pass it into the function.

```
p_list <- c(0.50,0.45,0.65,0.55)
```

We get the probability by position

```
died <- function (vec, day, p_list) {
   purrr::modify_if(vec,  ~.x == day, ~rbinom(1, 1,p_list[day]) * day)
}

set.seed(123)
status <- as.numeric(sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE))
died(vec = status, day = 3, p_list)
#[1] 0 3 0 2 3 2 2 2 3 1
```

To apply this for different days, we can use a `for` loop.

```
day <- 4
for(i in seq_len(day)) {
   status <- died(vec = status, day = i, p_list)
}
```

Comment: Thx Ronak.  How could I edit the function so it would do all four "days" at one call?  Tried this and failed

Comment: @JimMaas Would you be interested in a solution which does not use `modify_if` ?

Comment: Sure! thx.  It will be done a lot in a big simulation so effeciency/speed will be an issue.

Comment: Thanks again, thought there might be some simple way of doing it with an apply statement.  I tried a couple but no luck.

Comment: I don't find `for` loops difficult as such. The reason why `apply` or other looping structures won't work directly here is because here 1 iteration of `died` returns only part of `status` and after all the iterations we need to combine all. Although I think there should be some way to change `died` function itself so that it could run for all the days together.